# Php: Upload Large Files 

Tags: php, upload, nginx

Can anyone help me to **code** for **uploading** very big files like **1Gb** on a PHP website?

nginx can use?

some on told nginx is good, some tells thats not good have to use event based servers.
Please give me a solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something like:

**nginx.conf**

```
client_max_body_size           1024m;
```

**php.ini**

```
post_max_size = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
```

That should work just fine.

Please do note that HTTP is not really the best protocol for this type of file transfers, and you are dependent on browsers even if you get everything to work on your side.

Comment: Thank you Dow
Can you pls help me with come more details, I am familiar with php.ini, but not in nginx.conf
Can you pls give it in details.

Thankx aagain

Comment: You can read more about configuring nginx here: http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration, particularly here: http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2010/07/nginx-primer/. Please accept the answer if this is what you need.

Comment: Dow,
I still cant reach the target. Can you help me by ending any sample codes for big file upload pls.and let me know the installation code and installation methosed pls, if pssible pls mail me to techworld91 at g mail. c om

Comment: If you have trouble installing or configuring nginx and php, ask a new question here on SO, describing the trouble you are having and the errors you are getting. I can't help you if you don't describe what is going wrong, and I am not going to write a manual for you, or do it for you.